# Open source Asp.Net Master page Templates

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

Where can I download  Open source Asp.Net Master page Templates?

Answer (score 6):

You could try http://openwebdesign.org/

Search for free asp.net masterpage templates

Comment: looking for some more such sources..

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't make sense you can use any template to use with master pages , just copy the html and related files and paste it in your master file.
Meanwhile you can check these websites

http://www.m6.net/resources/asp.net-web-templates.aspx